# tomcat8-maven-plugin not found even after importing plugin in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-tomcat-plugin, tomcat8.5

I added `tomcat8-maven-plugin` as a plugin to my pom.xml, but still when I run `mvn tomcat8:run` I get the following error back:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat8' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/v4g4x/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.Varun.IWPL</groupId>
    <artifactId>RESTTourism</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RESTTourism</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>RESTTourism</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat8-maven-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0-r1756463</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.34</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Tomcat Version: 8.5.60
JDK Version: 8 & 11

Comment: have you tried mvn clean install.

Comment: ```mvn clean compile```? Yes. I do not want to run ```install``` because I don't unnecessarily want this program's war to be added to my local repository. Besides, even if I did that, the tomcat8 plugin which seems to be missing, won't appear.

Comment: The artifact you added to your `pom.xml` is not in the Maven Central repository: cf. [MvnRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat8-maven-plugin?repo=alfresco-public).

Comment: Okay so apparently running `tomcat:run` instead of 'tomcat8:run' gets this working.
But on Tomcat6 for some reason.